# Best Practices for Favorites Feature in App

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that, like many apps today, allows users to browse posts and favorite them so that they're stored in a list for future access. Currently my stack is Firebase Database for the back-end, and Swift iOS for the client, but this is more a question about general best practices.

In my app, there are many places where a user can view a post, and for all of them it shows if they've already favorited it or not. How I'm achieving this now is by saving the post's UID to a list for each user in Firebase, so it can be compared against every time a user views a post in the app. This works fine, but I'm not sure if its scalable because it requires fetching the entire list of favorited post UIDs for the current user every time they enter the app. For a few tens or hundreds of favorited posts this doesn't seem to be an issue, but after a few years and thousands of favorites I'm thinking it might become a drag on data, memory and processing.

Are there more efficient best practices for this type of feature? The nice thing is it would apply to lots of other types of features as well, such as likes and friends lists.

**Edit:**

This is how my Firebase database is setup at the moment. Again, this structure currently does work for me, and I've had no issues with it yet, but I'm not sure if its scalable fetching the entire list of `favoritedPostIds` for the current user every time they log in. I am fully willing to restructure the entire database if there's a better way.

```
posts {
    post-1-UID {
        title: "post1",
        text: "blah"
    },
    post-2-UID {
        title: "post2",
        text:"blahblah" 
    }
},
users {
    user-1-UID {
        name: "User1",
        email: "user1@email.com"
    },
    user-2-UID {
        name: "User2",
        email: "user2@email.com"
    }
},
favoritedPostIds {
    user-1-UID {
        post-2-UID: "2019-11-19T19:12:51.240GMT-05:00"
    },
    user-2-UID {
        post-1-UID: "2019-10-16T19:10:57.340GMT-05:00",
        post-2-UID: "2019-11-24T11:21:05.610GMT-05:00"
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using Firestore, just curious? Pricing model?

Comment: @bsod I started this project a couple years before Firestore was released. I’ll probably migrate over in the future.

Comment: To answer this question accurately, we would really need to see a snippet of your firebase structure and the associated code. We would also need to understand what that code does / what you are expecting it to do. Can you update and clarify your question? Also, take a look at these two posts [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay Thanks. I included a snippet of how my database is setup.

Comment: You're instinct is correct, it isn't going to scale well and eventually will overload the device. There are a few solutions but how your UI flows is unclear. Are you stating all of the users favorites are loaded when they log in and as they select other posts to view, you compare that with the loaded posts and if it exists, you indicate it's already a favorite? If that is the flow, then why not just query or .observeSingle that users favoritedPostIds whenever selects a post to view to see if it exists? That avoids loading anything on login.

Comment: @Jay That's a good point about the UI. I show the favorites button, which reflects whether or not the current user has favorited the post, in several tableviews throughout the app. It's a similar setup to Instagram. My concern about doing a query for each post is that as I prefetch the posts as the user scrolls I'd now have to make an extra call to the database for each one. Maybe that's not as bad as it sounds though. It could probably be made more efficient if it was done in a cloud function too.

Comment: I would just make the extra call for each post. You're using the realtime database and it really is blisteringly fast so that extra call for each post would just be a few lines of code to see if it's a favorite, and since you're pre-loading it would have minimal, if any impact.

Comment: @Jay I tried that out and it seems to work really well so far. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> after a few years and thousands of favorites I'm thinking it might become a drag on data, memory and processing

In that case you should not retrieve favorite as user property, but rather as a property of a post. Your backend should store it in database in either way or even both (as property of user of as property of a post) and client would just get information was any particular post favorited by current user or not.

However it could be difficult to implement on backed side with Firebase database (especially if one post is added to favotites by thousands of users).
So I would suggest to store favorite data partially, like chunks of favorited posts ordered by post date or even in tree-like structure to get small part of favorite post ids by post id range. This would not affect most users, but some users might wait a little longer to get this information.